# Cambiar fill color a un svg en un selector ::after

Tags: css, svg

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el atributo fill del svg al hacer `hover` en el elemento `<a>`? Hasta donde he visto solo se puede si el svg es declarado explícitamente, pero no sé si es posible cuando está en un selector `::after`

```css
.menuint-item {
    background: #444;
}
.menuint-item li a{
  color: #AAA !important;
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Oxygen";
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.menuint-item li a:hover{
  color: #F9C017 !important;
}
.menuint-item li a::after {
    content: ' ';
    background-image: url('http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B0we2ZlPETdKVnJONWNLUF9iODQ');
    float: right;
    background-size: 14px 14px;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuint-item">
  <li><a href="#">Programa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Programa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Programa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Programa</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final tuve que generar dos archivos `svg` idénticos, con la única diferencia de que cambié el `fill` color, uno blanco y otro amarillo, y en el `hover` cambio el archivo:

```css
.menuint-item {
  background: #444;
}
.menuint-item li a{
  color: #AAA !important;
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Oxygen";
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.menuint-item li a:hover{
  color: #F9C017 !important;
}
.menuint-item li a::after {
    content: ' ';
    background-image: url('http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B0we2ZlPETdKVnJONWNLUF9iODQ');
    float: right;
    background-size: 14px 14px;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.menuint-item li a:hover::after {
    background-image: url('http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B0we2ZlPETdKbnJLR0dwMEZrOGs');
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuint-item">
  <li><a href="#">Programa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Programa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Programa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Programa</a></li>
</ul>
```