# Rellenar un SVG utilizando " fill "

Tags: html, css3, svg, hover

Cuando tengo, por ejemplo, un hexágono hecho en SVG, el cual tiene solo dibujado el borde... Y cuando haga un :hover ese hexágono se rellene del color del borde... ¿Cómo puedo utilizar el attributo (si se puede llamar así) " fill " ?

Imaginense un hexágono con el borde azul y el relleno transparente, pero cuando paso raton (:hover) quiero que se rellene del mismo color que el borde...

Actualmente manejo ese :hover empleando dos imágenes sobre el mismo hexágono, uno vacío y otro relleno. Sé que éste método no es eficiente, por ello me gustaría comprender cómo utilizar el " fill " para solucionarlo (si es posible)...

¡Saludos!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com). 
Te invito a mirar [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: @Mr.Manutri igual te viene bien este enlace: [¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1058/15855) ^^

Comment: @lois6b gracias

Comment: Este ejemplo puede ser muy útil para lo que necesitas: https://codepen.io/luiscarvalho/pen/hJFrx

Comment: revisa esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87513/cambiar-fill-color-a-un-svg-en-un-selector-after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente añádele el atributo `fill="none"` al HTML para no tener contenido dentro del elemento. El borde se lo podrás añadir con los atributos `stroke-width` para ponerle la anchura que quieres que tenga el borde y `stroke` para el color.

Por último, desde CSS le puedes modificar la propiedad `fill`.

```css
svg:hover .circulo{
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="115" height="115">
  <circle class="circulo" stroke-width="3px" stroke="blue" cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

**NOTA**: En este caso he utilizado un círculo para simplificar el código pero el comportamiento sería exactamente el mismo con un hexágono.

Comment: Gracias ! Pronto lo pondré a prueba con muchas figuras para probar !